# In which formula is used to calculate the Duration function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please anyone can share your opinion for in which formula is used to calculate the duration function in Excel.

I need formula for this Excel function = DURATION( settlement, maturity, coupon, yld, frequency, [basis] )

Comment: That depends I guess. How is the data formated?

Comment: Can you pls provide more details? Duration means interns of days or hours or mins etc...

Comment: I know this is an old comment @vanathaiyan, but the person who originally asked the question provided the DURATION call from Excel. DURATION in Excel is a specific financial formula, so no more details were needed to know what DURATION means.

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses the same formula as explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_duration#Periodically_compounded) for calculation Macauley duration.

[image]

As of the example from [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DURATION-function-b254ea57-eadc-4602-a86a-c8e369334038?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

[image]

Formulas:

`B7`: `=DURATION(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6)`

`E2` downwards: `=D2/$B$5`

`F2` downwards: `=$B$3/$B$5*100`

`F17`: `=$B$3/$B$5*100+100`

`G2` downwards: `=F2/(1+($B$4/$B$5))^($B$5*E2)`

`H2` downwards: `=E2/$G$18*G2`

`G18`and `H18`are the sums of the cells above.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. And Please anyone can share your opinion to calculate the duration formula if we given the settlement date and maturity date given like this =DURATION(39000,40000,0.08,0.09,2,3).

Comment: @Thirumurugan: Hm, no I have no idea how Microsoft calculates `DURATION` while there are fractions of periods. With integer periods it is as shown. In my opinion for calculating Macauley duration periods have to be integer values. Definitely Excel's calculation cannot be right since `=DURATION(39000,39913,0.08,0.09,2,3)` - 5 semi-annual periods  - calculates `2.312563887` while `=DURATION(39000,39914,0.08,0.09,2,3)` - 5 semi-annual periods plus one day  - calculates `2.223071273`. Thats illogically.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The Duration() function in Excel "Returns the Macauley duration for an assumed par value of $100. Duration is defined as the weighted average of the present value of the cash flows and is used as a measure of a bond price's response to changes in yield."

source: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/DURATION-function-b254ea57-eadc-4602-a86a-c8e369334038?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

To calculate a time duration, i.e. the elapsed time between two date/time values, you can just subtract the start date/time from the end date/time.

Date/Time values in Excel are stored with days as integers and time as decimals. depending on the magnitude of the calculated duration, the result can show days or hours, or both. In the following screenshot a few durations have been formatted with different custom formats. The formula to calculate the duration is `=B1-A1` applied to the respective row.

[image]